# Cannot close oracle database connection successfully using jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, scala, jdbc, oracle11g

I’m able to connect to an oracle database through scala with ojdbc but and have no problems running queries but when closing the connection I get a SQLException that mentioned three different errors

“ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1”

“ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows”

“ORA-06512: at line 6”

I opened a connection, ran a query successfully, then tried to close the connection but I got that error. I’ve tried different versions of the ojdbc driver but with no success.

```
val conn = DriverManager.getConnection(oracleURL, oracleUser, oraclePassword)
val statement = conn.createStatement()
val results = statement.executeQuery(query)
statement.close()
conn.close()
```

The line conn.close() is the one failing.

Comment: and where is your [mcve]?

Comment: Added the code sample, like I said the query is working fine. It’s specifically when closing that I’m having the error. This doesn’t allow me to use Spark to load the tables since Spark internally calls the close function which fails.

Comment: and where is the query?

Comment: The query is a simple select “SELECT * FROM table WHERE ROWNUM <= 1000”

Comment: `ORA-06512` is PL/SQL error which is raised by some callable unit (function/procedure/trigger) in the database. Do you have any PL/SQL code involved in your actual statement? Does it run fine in SQL IDE/console (for example, SQL Developer)?

Comment: No, I’m only running that select. It works fine when I was using cx_oracle with python. It seems to be an issue specific to jdbc. When connecting to a SQL Server db I don’t have this issue either.

Comment: Shot in the dark, perhaps: does it help if you try disabling auto-commit by using  `conn.setAutoCommit(false);` ?

Comment: Obviously this general code path is heavily tested and works. For it to fail in your case means there's something unusual happening. The only way anyone is going to be able to help you is to have a complete reproducible test case so that we can see all the details. The generic code you've given obviously works so its the devil is in the details. To get an answer you need to provide all the details, a complete reproducible test case.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this

```
val conn = DriverManager.getConnection(oracleURL, oracleUser, oraclePassword)
try {
  val statement = conn.createStatement()
  val results = statement.executeQuery(query)
catch { case e => log or something }
finally {
  statement.close()
  conn.close()
}
```